# How is recursion executed when there are 2 recursive statements like the program below?

Tags: java, recursion

I had posted a question earlier however I wasn't clear enough. I am sorry for the confusion but what I meant was if there is a program like :

```
TreeNode createMinBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
    if(end< start) return null;

    int mid = (start+end)/2;
    Treenode n= new Treenode(arr[mid]);
    n.left= createMinBST(arr, start, mid-1)  //LINE a
    n.right= createMinBST(arr, mid+1, end);  //LINE b
    return n;
}
```

How does LINE a and LINE b unroll(like it said in coding interview book) or how does it work? Does LINE a go all the way to the base case and return values and then LINE b executes? Or both the recursive statements go down to the base case simultaneously?

If someone could explain level wise path for creating a Minimal BST from the code given above, it will be really helpful to understand how multiple recursive statements (here 2- Line a and Line b) takes place

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you just follow the program flow by hand?  Or observe what happens for real by stepping through it in a debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple Recursion unrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770492/multiple-recursion-unrolling)

Comment: @Mat- I posted it again here as my question got closed for not being clear enough.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I wouldn't have asked if I knew the answer. I tried but I have having trouble, hence I asked for help.

Comment: @user807496: Take a piece of paper, and draw out a box for every time a function gets called, with a line connecting it to its "parent".   In each box, write down the current values of the parameters. That is how to figure out program flow.

Comment: If you do not how how to use a debugger, you can print out the variables at the start of your method, and possible even a [`Thread.dumpStack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack()) to determine where you are in your program

Comment: Debugger is necessary. Learn it. It's a pain at first, but I gunaratee that you will love debugger. "print statements" are essentially basic debug tools. Just print "level i:  print array" where i the level, and array is the current result. sometime similiar.

Comment: @CppLearner More important than learning how to use a debugger, is learning how to trace code on paper/in your thoughts imho. a) This will help you write better code in the first place (so no debugger at all maybe) and b) some day you'll get into situations where a debugger won't help you (and this day it's not only real low level OS stuff or embedded systems - you can't debug data races in a debugger). So he should just follow Oli's suggestion and grab a piece of paper! (but afterwards learning how to use a debugger and checking if you've got it right can't harm either :) )

Comment: That's very true, Voo. Appreicate the honest opinon :) It's needed. With the right idea, you can verify the result using debugger and makes learning easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your code you're building your tree the same way you'd do a "depth-first search".  So you're going deeper (depper left in your case) until there's no more element to process, then you're going back up one level and then again back down.

*(btw your 'line A' is missing a semi-colon at the end)*

As is often the case when learning or trying to figure out how recursive calls are working, it is convenient to print out the calls.

For example in your case if your starting array contains numbers from [10..24] then your calls may look like this:

```
Calling minBST on 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24

    Calling minBST (left) on 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16

        Calling minBST (left) on 10, 11, 12

            Calling minBST (left) on 10

            Calling minBST (right) on 12

        Calling minBST (right) on 14, 15, 16

            Calling minBST (left) on 14

            Calling minBST (right) on 16

    Calling minBST (right) on 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24

        Calling minBST (left) on 18, 19, 20

            Calling minBST (left) on 18

            Calling minBST (right) on 20

        Calling minBST (right) on 22, 23, 24

            Calling minBST (left) on 22

            Calling minBST (right) on 24
```

Comment: Good analysis...now reward yourself with a nice SO display name :)

Comment: @Paul: ah ah, I'll do that soon : )

Answer (score 1):

The code is executed in order.

So, the first time `n.left` is hit, it must execute that statement before the next line is executed. That means yes, it "saves" its spot and goes all the way down the recursive tree from `n.left` before it has *completed* the `n.left` line and then can continue with execution (on to `n.right`).

Answer (score 1):

user9889052 did a nice trace. The simpler answer is top to bottom. Until the top recursion (at each level) is returned, the recursions below will not be executed.

By convention I would say the left is always the top-er statement.

In fact, recursion is nothing more than a tree.

```
                            Root
                     /                    \
                  RecurA                RecurB
               /         \
        RecurAa        RecurAb
        /     \
      RAaa    RAaab
    /     \
  dead    dead
```

**EDIT**
When a dead (return) is reached, it goes to the right, and until all the nodes of the same level are "dead" (all the recursion statements are returned), it goes back one level up, and expand **RAaab**.

Side question: can you guess the depth of this tree? This become apparent why recursion can be problemic if the subproblems are bad.

Recursion works since at each call (each level call), a stack frame is created. Previous level's infomation are "stored". When you begin poping (going backward, as you hit a return statement), info saved for the previous level are now restore back. The mechanism is a lot more complicated than this simple description.

MinBST might be a bad idea at first. Try this recursion instead.

```
Given an array [3,4,9,2,0,11,8,-1,2,4]
Partition this array in halves until size of each partition is one
Then give the sum of the left and right partition as they return (at each level)
```