# Understanding this recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

Hello fellow programmers.

For some time now, recursive programming have been one of the things i understand the least. Because of that i decided, that i needed to use some time, understanding and programming a few basic examples. The problem is that i have this assignment i solved, but dont quite understand how it works -.-

If someone could help me understand it, i would appreciate it.

Thanks, in advance.

- Teilmann

Assignment:

A dominopiece has the size 2*1. A board has the length n and width 2. Create a recursive method that returns the number of ways, whereas a board can be covered by dominopieces.

My method:

```
public static int dominobrik(int n){
    int sum;

    if(n >= 0 && n <= 2){
        sum = n;
    } else {
        sum = dominobrik(n-1) + dominobrik(n-2);
    }

    return sum;

}
```

Comment: Pick a small *n*. Trace through the code on paper--"play computer". Write down each step, indenting for each level of recursion. Alternatively, step through in a debugger, but IMO playing computer is a more reliable path to enlightenment.

Comment: yeah, i actually tried that.. But my brain is kind of lagging after programming for 8-9 hours straight. :) Thx anyway

Comment: What are the other options? We can't inject knowledge ;)

Comment: How do you know you solved it?

Comment: i forgot to say, that it was an old school assignment i solved over 1 year ago. Sorry for the lack of info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help people understand this kind of recursive calls I really think that nicely printing things out really helps.

The output of the program has been indented according to the recursion depth.

Here are the 8 paths taken to reach all the solution for a width of 5, when doing:

```
dominobrik(n-2) + dominobrik(n-1)
```

*(notice that for each new path, the recursive calls first adds the two horizontal pieces if possible)*

*(also note that this is different than the code you posted, where you wrote (n-1) first and then (n-2), but it really doesn't change much)*

```
So far the board is: 
.....
.....

     So far the board is: 
     --...
     --...

          So far the board is: 
          ----.
          ----.

               Finished board:
               ----|
               ----|


          So far the board is: 
          --|..
          --|..

               Finished board:
               --|--
               --|--


               So far the board is: 
               --||.
               --||.

                    Finished board:
                    --|||
                    --|||


     So far the board is: 
     |....
     |....

          So far the board is: 
          |--..
          |--..

               Finished board:
               |----
               |----


               So far the board is: 
               |--|.
               |--|.

                    Finished board:
                    |--||
                    |--||


          So far the board is: 
          ||...
          ||...

               So far the board is: 
               ||--.
               ||--.

                    Finished board:
                    ||--|
                    ||--|


               So far the board is: 
               |||..
               |||..

                    Finished board:
                    |||--
                    |||--


                    So far the board is: 
                    ||||.
                    ||||.

                         Finished board:
                         |||||
                         |||||
```

Comment: @Thomas Teilmann: no problem!  If you liked that answer, you may want to look at this (accepted too) anwser I made here, about another "tracing recursion" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771731/how-is-recursion-executed-when-there-are-2-recursive-statements-like-the-program/8772301#8772301

Answer (score 1):

In the base case, where `n = 1`, there is only 1 way to arrange the domino on the board, and that's horizontally. Where `n = 2`, there are 2 ways to arrange the dominoes. Either you can arrange both vertically, or both horizontally.

For the case where `n = 3`, the 3 ways are:

1. 1 horizontally across the top, and two vertically beneath;
2. 1 horizontally across the bottom, and 2 vertically above;
3. or all 3 horizontally, stacked.

Note that in the `n = 3` case, you have repeated both of the arrangements of the `n = 2` case, but to these, you have added the arrangement from the `n = 1` case. Recall that the only valid arrangement for `n = 1` is a single horizontal domino. Each of the cases in `n = 3` has at least 1 horizontal domino.

You can extend this to the `n = 4` case. Take all of the possible combinations above for `n = 3`, then add all of the combinations for `n = 2`, stacking them appropriately given the problem's constraints.

I wish I could illustrate this, but it may help to draw them out on some squared paper.

Comment: Thx dude. I really appreciated your post. It was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Le't say you know the answer for `n` and you want the answer for `n + 1`.

For some of the solutions for `n`, you have the last domino standing vertically and for the others, the last two dominos are stacked horizontally one over the other.

If the last two dominos are horizontal, all you can do is add your `n + 1` domino vertically.  However if the last domino is vertical, then you can add it vertically too, or you can flip it horizontally with the previous domino.

I would keep track not only of how many solutions there are for a given `n`, but also of how many of those are terminating with the last domino horizontal/vertical.

I'll let you figure out the rest since this is homework. Also I haven't really figured out the complete solution.  It's possible it will turn out to be equivalent to the solution you posted.

Comment: Thx for giving me some understanding on the subject.. Just what i needed :)